# Dynamically store api response in a new array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, parent-child

I am trying to solve a problem to store api responses when i click on a checkbox with the label of the checkbox as the variable name and haven't been successful, hence asking for some help here.
Here is the problem description,

I have a component which has a multiple checkboxes, each checkbox is a child component.
When i click on a checkbox, it makes an api call and the response is an array. I want to save this response in a variable where the name of the variable is the label of the checkbox in the parent component and make this array available through the parent component.
I cannot have state variables because that would mean that i have these variables declared before hand, i want only as many variables as many checkboxes are clicked. Is there any way where i can achieve this?

**Parent Component**

```
render() {
    const {itemList} = this.props
    return (
     <div>

        {
          itemList && itemList.map((item, i) => {
              return(
                <div className="checkbox">
                  <MyCheckbox key={i} item={item} actions={this.props.actions} dispatch={this.props.dispatch} />
                </div>
              )
          })
        }
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
 toggle = (Id) => {
    const { key, actions, dispatch} = this.props
    dispatch(actions.makeApiCall(key.Id, Id))

      this.setState(prevState => 
            ({ 
                checked: !prevState.checked,
                loader : true
            })
        )
  }

  render() {
    const item = this.props.item

    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox label={item.name} 
        onChange={() => this.toggle(item.Id)} checked={this.state.checked} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So as you can see when i make an api call, the redux has the response of the api call, now i want that response in a variable with the variable name being the label of the checkbox.

I tried having a call back function in the parent for the toggle function in my checkbox component, but with that i will only have the name of the label, not able to get the updated api responses. 
From what i can think i can create variable names with the label of the checkbox through the call back function, but those will be available locally in the call back function. Hence i cannot use those to store the api response if i use the `componentWillReceiveProps` function to get new responses.

Can anybody help me with this? Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of redux. Steps to do the same:
1) Make a redux method to set the key of the checkbox. (Note: this is not a api call, you will just set the key in your store on click of toggle fxn)
Something like:

```
export const setCheckBoxKey(key){
   return { ...state, key }
};
```

2) Then, when api is called, you can set the response in that specific key in reducer of that api call as the state is accessible in reducer.

for eg:

```
const apiReducer(state, action) {
  const newResponseObject = {...state.responseObject, [state.key]: action.payload.data }; // where action.payload.data is your api response which is an array

  return {...state, responseObject: newResponseObject };
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not totally convinced with this method. The purpose of the redux store is to reuse the already retrieved data which might be used else where, but this is a component where the data retrieved will not be used else where. I do not want to store this in the redux store, looking at some way to store data locally in the component when actually required.